# Webdriver Selenium click a <li> element inside an Iframe

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, iframe, webdriver, html-lists

[![enter image description here][1]][1]trying to click and select the marked

element.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIRn8.png

#The options - https://i.stack.imgur.com/e66m1.png

using

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Current attempt:

> `driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("moduleManagement")) driver.find_element_by_class_name("ranges").find_element_by_tag_name("ul").find_element_by_tag_name("li").click()`

I need help with how to select a

element . where i worng

Comment: Is that the second li tag you wanna select  ?

Comment: yes indeed.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to use **explicit wait** to `switch to frame` and interact with them :

to click on second li tag, below code should work for you.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "moduleManagement")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#colorbox+div[class^='daterangepicker']"))).click()
second_li_element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//li[@data-range-key])[2]")))
second_li_element.click()
```

**Imports  :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Ill take your advice in mind , i switched to explicit wait  but my problem is how i can choose the second li text to be selected.

Comment: make use of these two lines `second_li_element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//li[@data-range-key])[2]")))
second_li_element.click()` - I have provided you these in the above answer

Comment: Firstly thank you for your support!.                                                                                 so, i want it to be auto without touch my mouse , as for now it succeed but only when i " help the program" and click the "dropdownlist" in the site that changed to the second li element.

Comment: oh okay, I thought you already have the code to click on drop down list, anyway  use this line to first click on main drop down : - `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#colorbox+div[class^='daterangepicker']"))).click()` - even I have updated the code above

Comment: I still see that it force me to click first and then that work , i need some function that works like "from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select" that automaticlly clicked on your deserved element.

Comment: That still not working for me unfortunatlly :(

Comment: You cannot use select from selenium cause the Html doesn't contain select and option tag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234322/discussion-between-ben-cohen-and-cruisepandey).

Comment: Can you do this : open chrome and then to go to dev tools (press F12) and then elements -> then do CTRL + F -> and then search for `div#colorbox+div[class^='daterangepicker']`, if there's a match you would see a highlighted tag with 1/1 or 1/2 or 1/3... and so on